# Тире в предложении, в котором подлежащее и сказуемое существительные

Tags: пунктуация

Твоя поездка за самокатом приключение?

Можно ли в данном случае не ставить тире?

Comment: А где инверсия?

Comment: Может, с самокатом?

Comment: Нет, за самокатом — за покупкой самоката.

Comment: Не говорят "*приключение за самокатом*". Не хватает слов для понимания смысла.

Comment: Твоя поездка — приключение

Comment: А смысл где?  Приведите контекст, чтобы было понятно, о чем речь. Как можно ИЗУЧАТЬ тему и обобщать что-либо с помощью придуманных предложений, когда даже смысл их неясен. Или придумайте ситуацию тоже.

Comment: @Владимир Примечание: Если "*за самокатом*" относится к первой части, то без тире нельзя. Первая часть должна быть нераспространена, чтобы на неё не падало ударение. (Если отвечаете на чей-то комментарий к вопросу, необходимо обращение через @, чтобы пришло оповещение.)

Answer (score 1):

1) Так как в начальном варианте вопроса присутствовало слово ***инверсия***, то можно предположить, что автора заинтересовало следующее правило Розенталя

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Примечание. Обычно тире **не ставится**:

6) если сказуемое предшествует подлежащему: Прекрасный человек Иван Иванович! (Г.); Славное место эта долина! (Л.); Живописный народ индийцы (Гонч.); Неплохой ученик этот мальчик. **Постановка тире** в этом случае подчеркивает интонационное деление предложения на два состава: Славные люди — соседи мои! (П.);

**Можно ли применить это правило к заданному предложению**? Да, если ситуация будет понятна, но только не для вопросительного предложения.

В качестве примера: *Это твоЯ поездка за самокатом приключение, а другие могут приобрести его безо всякого труда.*

Это вполне понятная фраза: даже в письменном варианте ясно, что логическое ударение смещено, поэтому пауза перед сказуемым не делается и тире не ставится.

Возможно, автор имел в виду что-то другое, но я объясняю **важность понимания ситуации.**

2) **Попробуем оставить авторское (вопросительное) предложение.**

Например: *А что ты называешь приключением? Вот твоя поездка за самокАтом — приключЕние?*

**Неуклюжее предложение?** Нет, оно стало нормальным, как только появился контекст.

Тире ставится **по обычным правилам**, предложение состоит из двух фраз и имеет два ударения. Но почему задан такой вопрос, если это классический вариант для постановки тире? Опять приходится **догадываться**.

**Почему-то кажется, что там нет паузы**? Это связано с **вопросительной** интонацией — ударение в конце фразы более заметно, на его фоне в меньшей степени обозначены пауза и ударение на предыдущем слове.

Answer (score 0):

Когда и подлежащее, и сказуемое выражены существительными в именительном падеже, тире обязательно.

Розенталь допускает несколько исключений, все они в основном связаны с наличием слов-связок, которых тут нет.

Розенталь дает совершенно определенные, однозначные правила, а не "расписывает случаи".

Comment: Расписывание случаев - совсем не означает что-то неопределённое и неоднозначное. Исключения как раз являются случаями в языке, а не выдуманными кем-то правилами.

Comment: @bypasser3  Пожалуйста, прочитайте вступление к правилам Розенталя: ...если в области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, то к пунктуации это требование НЕПРИМЕНИМО. Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает ФОРМАЛЬНЫЙ подход к соблюдению правил.

Comment: А вот пример из этой темы: 8. Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое — формой И.п.существительного, тире между ними ОБЫЧНО не ставится:  Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Ч.).

Однако тире в этом случае ставится:

1) при ЛОГИЧЕСКОМ подчеркивании: Я — хранитель твоему добру… (Цв.);

Comment: Посмотрите на пример из вопроса, пожалуйста! Разве там подлежащее выражено личным местоимением?

Answer (score 0):

Главный секрет в том, что тире можно не ставить, если по задумке автора логическое ударение не падает на первую часть. Соответственно, тогда нет никакой паузы. Но это далеко не всегда возможно. Если бы "*за самокатом*" относилось ко второй части, то можно было бы прочитать без ударения (и не ставить тире). Этому способствует именно инверсия. Но при примыкании оборота к первой части, она становится распространённой и ударение падает на неё (тире нужно).

Розенталь лишь расписал случаи, когда это рационально — чаще всего происходит.

Comment: В каких случаях логическое ударение падает на первую часть, как это определить?

Comment: Падает, если вы хотите дать определение какому-то понятию. Если есть ударение - есть и пауза как следствие. То есть довольно легко определить на слух.

Comment: oleedd, вы, кажется, опять ставите логические ударения в виртуальных конструкциях. Тогда не стоит удивляться, что вам задают дополнительные вопросы, причем ваши ответы на эти вопросы выглядят неубедительно.

Comment: А что, не отвечать, если пример странный?

Comment: Если сложно понять смысл странного примера, то лучше не отвечать. Другой вариант - уточнить у автора. Еще один вариант -  догадаться, о чем автор спрашивает, если он на ваши замечания не отвечает и на связь не выходит. Попробовать отредактировать пример и тогда отвечать на него. Правда, здесь нужно уметь читать между строк или иметь некоторые экстрасенсорные способности.

Comment: Скажу прямо: я ориентируюсь на структуру и грамматику, а не на смысл или то, в каких случаях так могут сказать (но если варианты зависят от смысла, то обязательно это расписываю). Здесь бесплатная помощь, а не оплачиваемый объёмный анализ. Если вообще не понимаю смысл, то уточняю.

Comment: Скажу прямо: вы делаете грубую ошибку.  Содержание определяет форму, а не наоборот, это всеобщий закон. Структура и грамматика - это форма, и вы хотите работать с ней, не зная, что она выражает? И бесплатный сервис тут ни при чем.  Ресурс дает отвечающим возможность общения и озвучивания своего мнения, своих идей. А задающий вопрос предоставляет тему для ответов.Получается круг взаимных услуг.

Comment: Нет тут грубой ошибки. Конечно, я понимаю смысл, но не зацикливаюсь на нём. Мне всё равно, где такое могут сказать. Не говорить же, что не буду отвечать, раз фразу вряд ли станут употреблять (она неудачная). Другое дело, если спрашивают о стилистике. Вообще, условия задачи не меняют, а вы это любите делать. Хотя если поменять что-то в примерах из ваших вопросов, то "ругаетесь". Услугу получает только тот, кто ищет ответы на что-то, а в другом случае просто тренировка мозгов на лингвистических задачках. То есть каждый решает своими методами, как ему хочется.

Comment: Как сейчас говорят, спасибо, я вас услышала. Помните у Пушкина: "Но потерял я только время, Благие мысли и труды..." Так я подумала, когда перечитала эту тему.  Меня здесь не услышал ни один человек. Лекция для зала, где все места пустые.  А вы тренируйте мозги, если в этом ваш интерес, удачи вам.

Comment: Я ваш ответ прочитал раньше - со всем согласен. "*Что сейчас русский язык?...*" Согласен. Меня удивляет, что нет никаких проектов учёных-лингвистов, где бы разбирали сложные, спорные случаи, расширяя, совершенствуя правила. Розенталь сделал очень много, но не всё. Есть сложные темы, где бы хотелось больше информации (так как есть много спорных случаев). Жаль, что он не жил в эпоху Интернета.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение совершенно правильное, хотя и звучит немного неуклюже из-за длинного дополнения. Твоя поездка за самокатом -  приключение?  Конечно же, здесь есть тире. Является ли твоя поездка за самокатом приключением? Смысл предложения сохранился бы и с добавлением "это".

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а можно считать правильным "немного неуклюжее" предложение? А вдруг в этой "неуклюжести" есть какой-то смысл. Инверсия, например, а вы этого не заметили. И еще такая просьба. Вы не могли бы обозначить ситуацию, когда может произноситься эта фраза. Ведь от  этого тоже может зависеть правильность предложения. Или нет?